# Read line by line from parameter file in function

Tags: bash, function, shell

I have a function with a parameter file. And I want to read it line by line.

**Condition**

If the lines are between `<?bash` and `?>` then I do `bash -c '$line'` else I display the line.

**Here my file (file):**

```
<html><head></head><body><p>Hello
<?bash
echo "world !"
?>
</p></body></html>
```

**Here my Bash script (bashtml):**

```
#!/bin/bash

function generation()
{
  while read line
  do
    if [ $line = '<?bash' ]
    then
      while [ $line != '?>' ]
      do
       bash -c '$line'
      done
    else
     echo $line
    fi
  done
}

generation $file
```

I execute this script:

```
./bashhtml
```

I am novice in Bash script and I'm lost

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: Following from Biffens comment, even if you did declare and call the function correctly it wouldn't work anyway as you don't get the new line after matching `<?bash` until you have left the if statement.

Comment: ...apart from the fact that you are not actually reading the file anywhere

Comment: The entire `while` loop is an antipattern anyway.  The quoting is wrong, too.  But something like `sed -n '1,/<?bash/d;/?>/,$d;p' file | sh` would perhaps work better altogether.

Comment: I was lost in my reasoning but thanks to your help I managed to implement my script. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you mean.  However, this code is HIGHLY DANGEROUS!  Any command inserted into those bash tags would be executed under your user id.  It could change your password, delete all your files, read or alter data, and so on.  Don't do it!

```
#!/bin/bash

function generation
{
  # If you don't use local (or declare) then variables are global
  local file="$1"              # Parameter passed to function, in a local variable
  local start=False            # A flag to indicate tags
  local line

  while read -r line
  do
    if [[ $line == '<?bash' ]]
    then
        start=True
    elif [[ $line == '?>' ]]
    then
        start=False
    elif "$start"
    then 
        bash -c "$line"      # Double quotes needed here
    else 
        echo "$line"
    fi
  done < "$file"             # Notice how the filename is redirected into read
}

infile="$1"                  # This gets the filename from the command-line
generation "$infile"         # This calls the function
```

Comment: I reworked my script with yours and now I understand better how to implement my function. Thanks :)

Comment: @XZKS:  note that I used double `[[` rather than single.  In this case they mean that the variable value `$line` does not need to be quoted, but there are other differences.  Feel free to ask further questions about this code if you are unsure of anything.